# Using 'old' database with django

Tags: python, django

I'm using a hand built (Postgres) database with Django. With "inspectdb" I was able to automatically create a model for it. The problem is that some tables have multiple primary keys (for many-to-many relations) and they are not accessible via Django.

What's the best way to access these tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to use composite primary keys in Django's ORM as of now (up to v1.0.2).

I can only think of three solutions/workarounds:

1. There is a [fork](http://github.com/dcramer/django-compositepks/tree/master) of django with a composite pk patch at github that you might want to try.
2. You could use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) together with Django.
3. You have to add a single field primary key field to those tables.

Comment: +1: Fix your database -- there shouldn't be multiple primary keys in any table.

Comment: @S.Lott: Mmm, that kind of comment is just asking to stir up the whole natural vs. surrogate keys debate.

Comment: option 3 is probably the easiest... it's an old database anyway

Answer (score 0):

Django does have support for [many-to-many relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships).  If you want to use a helper table to manage this relationships, the ManyToManyField takes a through argument which specifies the table to use.  You can't model anything terribly complex this way, but it is good for most simple applications.